# How to insert data into table during migration in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel 8 and sail with MYSQL as a database, and I have to create a countries table with all the countries with its name as "name" column, There are 194 countries in the world and I don't want to insert each country name one by one, is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: You can use seeder https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/seeding and you can read from txt or csv file also to import using seeder.

Comment: do you have any example?

Comment: The problem here is, that seeders are not automatically called on every deployment, but migrations are. If you have a 24/7 application in production, with no downtime allowed, it is possible to do the data seeding or manipulation right in the migration class. As far as I know there is no "Laravel way" of  automatically doing data manipulation on deployments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create Migrate first

```
php artisan make:migration create_countries_table
```

And in **create_countries_table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

---

And

```
php artisan make:seeder CountriesTableSeeder
```

And in  **CountriesTableSeeder**

```
public function run()
{
    DB::table('countries')->insert(
        ['name' => 'Afghanistan'],
        ['name' => 'Albania']
        ....
    );
}
```

> You can create seeder with Model as well `Country::create(`

---

**Useful Link**

1. [Laravel 8 Database Seeder Tutorial: Database Seeder](https://www.positronx.io/laravel-database-seeder-tutorial-example/)